# Topology on fractional ideals of a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups

Is there a natural (in some suitable sense) non discrete topology on the group of all non-zero fractional ideals of a number field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural topology is surely the subspace topology from the idele group of the global field, this is part of how we manage the surjection of $k_{\Bbb A}^\times\to Cl_k$ of the ideles onto the class group. The embedding is as usual given by letting $S$ be the set of (finite) primes of $k$ and mapping an ideal into $k_{\Bbb A}^\times$ via

> $$\mathfrak{a}\mapsto (1, 1, \ldots, 1)_\infty\times (\pi_p^{v_p(\mathfrak{a})})_{p\in S}$$

where $v_p$ is the valuation for the prime, $p$, and the $1$s are from the infinite places and the $\pi_p$ are local uniformizers at $p$, i.e. for the completion $k_p$.

Comment: Thanks! As I haven't properly studied adeles and ideles yet it didn't come to my mind!

Comment: @PaulTaylors if you are interested in an excellet topological treatment of the subject, at least from the basics up, I highly recommend Andre Weil's *Basic Number Theory*. It's not easy to read if you don't have much experience with number theory or topological groups, but based on the tags you used it seems you may have the requisite background not to get lost in the notation.